# Connect AWS EC2 instance to a domain on GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have an AWS EC2 instance. I created on the AWS console an elastic IP address ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.yy-yyyy-X.compute.amazonaws.com, and I got a domain name "my-domain.com" from GoDaddy.com

I used this [tutorial](http://fredericpaladin.com/kb/connect-aws-ec2-instance-to-godaddy-domain/) and others which were very similar to "link" my-domain.com to the EC2 instance elastic address. I went through all the steps, in the DNS manager, on GoDaddy, and I waited more than 72h now. When I try to connect to my-domain.com I am however redirected to a GoDaddy page saying that my-domain.com is parked free. Is there something that I am missing? Is the tutorial I followed outdated?

I am not sure how relevant it is to the above but I have an API set up on that AWS EC2 instance which is correctly responding when I go to http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.yy-yyyy-X.compute.amazonaws.com/api/my-endpoint. I am using Nginx and Gunicorn to deploy the api and it works like a charm. I however get redirected to "my-domain.com is parked free" when I try http://my-domain.com/api/my-endpoint.

And I am using indeed "http", in lieu of "https", to make connections to the api for now, I am looking to get a proper domain name attached to the EC2 instance before I go through the procedure of getting a proper SSL certificate. Could that be an issue too?

Thank you in advance
Cheers

[EDIT]

This is my config on GoDaddy.com

[image]

Where the black box is the copied / pasted "Public IPv4 address" (which corresponds to the elastic IP address I set up for the EC2 instance). Should I use the Public IPv4 DNS instead? (ecX-XX-XX-XX-XXX.yy-yyyy-X.compute.amazonaws.com). When I try the function "Dig" on https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/main/, it returns the wrong IP address for "my-domain.com". I am assuming it is returning one of GoDaddy.com IP with the "my-domain.com is parked free", but it is definitely not the elastic IP that I selected for my AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Your DNS record in GoDaddy is incorrect.  We can't find out what you did wrong without information about the DNS record you created.  HTTP is fine, it is not relevant for DNS lookups.

Comment: there is a DNS tool called dig ... run  `dig yourdomain.com`  or whatever your domain is ... it will display value of the type A record of that domain which MUST mention the IP address of the box ... your aws EC2 IP can be shown from your aws console -> EC2 -> Instances -> Instance ID -> Public IPv4 Address ... when you paste your domain into say a browser it does a DNS lookup to discover the IP address of the type A record to direct browser traffic to that IP using such a DNS lookup

Comment: goto aws to identify your IP address then update GoDaddy DNS type A record with that IP address then use dig to confirm the domain is linked to that IP

Comment: Thanks everyone, at least I know I'm on the right track! I updated my question with the config I entered on GoDaddy. I tried the DNS "Dig" function from Google and it definitely returns the wrong IP address. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and I can now correctly access my API on "my-domain.com"

As it turns out, the tutorial I shared initially as part of my question is incomplete and partly outdated I think: there is some configuration required on AWS using the service "Route 53". There is an excellent [tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRSj2n-XKGM) to guide you through the steps. I followed it and it solved my issue.

In a nutshell: when you open "Manage DNS" on GoDaddy.com, you have to enter custom name servers which are given to you by the AWS console after a bit of configuring.